# Convert a text file comprised of data separated by commas to an excel file using python

Tags: python, csv, text

I am pretty new to python and am working with some data from a weather station. The data is output to a text file where the data is separated by commas and new lines. I was wondering how I could write this data to a CSV file so I can process and graph the data in excel? I have never worked with text files before only CSV files so am unsure how to go about this.

Ideally, I would want to group the data by each day and calculate daily averages at the end of each set. I have included a sample of the dataset below. The data is in the following format: date, time, outside temp, outside humidity, dew point, wind speed, wind gust, avg wind bearing, rainfall rate, total rainfall, sea lvl pressure, rainfall counter, inside temp, inside humidity, latest gust, wind chill, heat index, uv index, solar rad, ET, annual et.

```
01/09/21,00:28,7.1,75,3.0,3.7,3.7,292,0.0,0.0,1025.8,81.9,17.1,44,3.7,4.6,7.1,0,0,0.00,0.00,3.0,0,0.0,292,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,00:58,7.0,75,2.9,5.1,5.1,248,0.0,0.0,1025.9,81.9,17.0,44,5.1,3.8,7.0,0,0,0.00,0.00,1.9,0,0.0,248,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,01:28,6.9,74,2.6,4.1,4.1,248,0.0,0.0,1025.8,81.9,17.0,44,4.1,4.1,6.9,0,0,0.00,0.00,2.5,0,0.0,248,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,01:58,6.9,74,2.6,4.8,4.8,292,0.0,0.0,1025.7,81.9,16.9,45,4.8,3.8,6.9,0,0,0.00,0.00,2.0,0,0.0,292,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,02:28,6.8,76,2.9,3.7,3.7,270,0.0,0.0,1025.5,81.9,16.9,45,3.7,4.2,6.8,0,0,0.00,0.00,2.7,0,0.0,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,02:58,6.7,76,2.8,3.1,3.1,270,0.0,0.0,1025.4,81.9,16.8,45,3.1,4.5,6.7,0,0,0.00,0.00,3.0,0,0.0,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,03:28,6.6,77,2.9,4.1,4.1,248,0.0,0.0,1025.5,81.9,16.8,45,4.1,3.8,6.6,0,0,0.00,0.00,2.2,0,0.0,248,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,03:58,6.3,77,2.6,2.7,2.7,292,0.0,0.0,1025.7,81.9,16.8,45,2.7,4.3,6.3,0,0,0.00,0.00,2.8,0,0.0,292,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,04:28,6.5,77,2.8,1.7,1.7,292,0.0,0.0,1025.7,81.9,16.7,45,1.7,5.4,6.5,0,0,0.00,0.00,3.8,0,0.0,292,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,04:58,6.4,77,2.7,1.7,1.7,292,0.0,0.0,1026.1,81.9,16.7,45,1.7,5.3,6.4,0,0,0.00,0.00,3.7,0,0.0,292,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,05:28,6.3,79,2.9,3.7,3.7,270,0.0,0.0,1026.5,81.9,16.7,45,3.7,3.6,6.3,0,0,0.00,0.00,2.2,0,0.0,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,05:58,6.3,80,3.1,3.7,3.7,292,0.0,0.0,1026.9,81.9,16.7,45,3.7,3.6,6.3,0,0,0.00,0.00,2.2,0,0.0,292,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,06:28,6.2,81,3.2,0.7,0.7,292,0.0,0.0,1027.3,81.9,16.6,45,0.7,6.2,6.2,0,0,0.00,0.00,4.2,0,0.0,292,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,06:58,6.4,80,3.2,1.7,1.7,270,0.0,0.0,1027.3,81.9,16.7,45,1.7,5.3,6.4,0,6,0.00,0.00,3.7,1,0.5,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,07:28,6.9,79,3.5,2.0,2.0,270,0.0,0.0,1027.5,81.9,16.7,45,2.0,5.6,6.9,0,19,0.00,0.00,4.1,40,0.5,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,07:58,7.5,77,3.7,2.7,2.7,270,0.0,0.0,1027.7,81.9,16.9,45,2.7,5.7,7.5,0,29,0.00,0.00,4.2,119,0.5,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,08:28,8.3,75,4.1,1.0,1.0,248,0.0,0.0,1027.6,81.9,17.3,43,1.0,8.3,8.3,0,36,0.00,0.00,6.3,212,0.5,248,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,08:58,9.1,74,4.7,2.0,2.0,270,0.0,0.0,1027.7,81.9,17.7,43,2.0,8.1,9.1,0,40,0.00,0.00,6.5,304,0.5,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,09:28,9.6,71,4.6,1.7,1.7,292,0.0,0.0,1027.7,81.9,18.0,43,1.7,9.0,9.6,0,44,0.00,0.00,7.2,391,0.5,292,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,09:58,10.8,67,4.9,6.8,6.8,248,0.0,0.0,1027.2,81.9,18.5,43,6.8,8.0,10.8,3,365,0.00,0.00,4.9,467,1.0,248,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,10:28,11.6,64,5.0,6.1,6.1,292,0.0,0.0,1027.0,81.9,18.8,43,6.1,9.2,11.6,3,402,0.00,0.00,6.2,531,1.5,292,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,10:58,12.1,63,5.3,7.1,7.1,314,0.0,0.0,1027.3,81.9,19.1,42,7.1,9.6,12.1,4,433,0.00,0.00,6.1,581,1.5,315,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,11:28,12.5,62,5.4,8.8,8.8,292,0.0,0.0,1027.1,81.9,19.4,42,8.8,9.7,12.5,4,492,0.00,0.00,5.3,616,2.0,292,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,11:58,12.6,62,5.5,8.2,8.2,270,0.0,0.0,1027.1,81.9,19.7,41,8.2,10.0,12.6,4,429,0.00,0.00,5.8,635,2.0,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,12:28,12.5,62,5.4,7.8,7.8,270,0.0,0.0,1026.8,81.9,20.0,40,7.8,10.0,12.5,1,124,0.00,0.00,6.0,637,2.0,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,12:58,13.0,60,5.4,4.8,4.8,292,0.0,0.0,1026.3,81.9,20.1,40,4.8,11.4,13.0,4,414,0.00,0.00,8.6,623,2.0,292,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,13:28,12.9,60,5.3,3.1,3.1,270,0.0,0.0,1025.9,81.9,20.2,40,3.1,11.9,12.9,0,59,0.00,0.00,9.7,592,2.0,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,13:58,12.8,60,5.2,3.1,3.1,270,0.0,0.0,1025.7,81.9,20.3,40,3.1,11.8,12.8,1,101,0.00,0.00,9.6,546,2.0,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,14:28,12.9,59,5.1,2.7,2.7,270,0.0,0.0,1025.5,81.9,20.3,40,2.7,12.1,12.9,0,47,0.00,0.00,9.9,485,2.0,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,14:58,12.8,59,5.0,3.1,3.1,270,0.0,0.0,1025.1,81.9,20.3,39,3.1,11.8,12.8,0,44,0.00,0.00,9.5,412,2.0,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,15:28,13.0,60,5.4,2.7,2.7,270,0.0,0.0,1025.2,81.9,20.5,39,2.7,12.3,13.0,0,40,0.00,0.00,10.1,328,2.0,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,15:58,12.5,60,4.9,5.1,5.1,270,0.0,0.0,1025.0,81.9,20.3,39,5.1,10.7,12.5,0,35,0.00,0.00,7.8,237,2.0,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,16:28,12.3,60,4.8,2.7,2.7,270,0.0,0.0,1025.2,81.9,19.9,40,2.7,11.4,12.3,0,29,0.00,0.00,9.2,143,2.0,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,16:58,12.0,62,4.9,1.7,1.7,292,0.0,0.0,1025.2,81.9,21.4,34,1.7,11.7,12.0,0,22,0.00,0.00,9.7,58,2.0,292,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,17:28,11.4,63,4.6,1.7,1.7,248,0.0,0.0,1025.4,81.9,19.7,40,1.7,11.1,11.4,0,11,0.00,0.00,9.0,5,2.5,248,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,17:58,10.8,67,4.9,2.7,2.7,292,0.0,0.0,1025.5,81.9,19.0,41,2.7,9.6,10.8,0,0,0.00,0.00,7.8,0,2.5,292,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,18:28,10.4,70,5.2,3.1,3.1,292,0.0,0.0,1025.9,81.9,18.7,43,3.1,8.9,10.4,0,0,0.00,0.00,7.1,0,2.5,292,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,18:58,10.0,73,5.4,1.7,1.7,270,0.0,0.0,1026.3,81.9,18.5,43,1.7,9.4,10.0,0,0,0.00,0.00,7.8,0,2.5,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,19:28,9.8,76,5.8,1.7,1.7,270,0.0,0.0,1026.6,81.9,18.3,44,1.7,9.2,9.8,0,0,0.00,0.00,7.6,0,2.5,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,19:58,9.4,78,5.8,1.7,1.7,292,0.0,0.0,1026.6,81.9,18.2,44,1.7,8.7,9.4,0,0,0.00,0.00,7.2,0,2.5,292,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,20:28,9.0,79,5.6,1.7,1.7,270,0.0,0.0,1026.8,81.9,18.1,44,1.7,8.3,9.0,0,0,0.00,0.00,6.8,0,2.5,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,20:58,8.8,79,5.4,2.0,2.0,270,0.0,0.0,1027.1,81.9,18.0,45,2.0,7.8,8.8,0,0,0.00,0.00,6.3,0,2.5,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,21:28,8.6,79,5.2,2.7,2.7,292,0.0,0.0,1027.2,81.9,17.9,45,2.7,7.0,8.6,0,0,0.00,0.00,5.6,0,2.5,292,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,21:58,8.3,79,4.9,2.0,2.0,270,0.0,0.0,1027.2,81.9,17.8,45,2.0,7.2,8.3,0,0,0.00,0.00,5.8,0,2.5,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,22:28,8.2,79,4.8,1.0,1.0,270,0.0,0.0,1027.3,81.9,17.7,46,1.0,8.2,8.2,0,0,0.00,0.00,6.3,0,2.5,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,22:58,7.6,80,4.4,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1027.2,81.9,17.7,46,0.0,7.6,7.6,0,0,0.00,0.00,6.4,0,2.5,0,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,23:28,7.2,81,4.2,1.0,1.0,270,0.0,0.0,1027.5,81.9,17.5,46,1.0,7.2,7.2,0,0,0.00,0.00,5.2,0,2.5,270,0.0,0.0
01/09/21,23:58,6.0,84,3.5,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1027.5,81.9,17.4,46,0.0,6.0,6.0,0,0,0.00,0.00,4.6,0,2.5,0,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,00:28,5.9,83,3.2,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1027.7,81.9,17.4,46,0.0,5.9,5.9,0,0,0.00,0.00,4.4,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,00:58,5.1,86,3.0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1028.0,81.9,17.3,46,0.0,5.1,5.1,0,0,0.00,0.00,3.6,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,01:28,5.1,87,3.1,0.7,0.7,270,0.0,0.0,1027.9,81.9,17.2,46,0.7,5.1,5.1,0,0,0.00,0.00,3.1,0,0.0,270,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,01:58,4.9,86,2.8,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1027.8,81.9,17.2,46,0.0,4.9,4.9,0,0,0.00,0.00,3.4,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,02:28,4.5,87,2.5,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1027.7,81.9,17.1,46,0.0,4.5,4.5,0,0,0.00,0.00,2.9,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,02:58,3.4,90,1.9,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1027.6,81.9,17.0,45,0.0,3.4,3.4,0,0,0.00,0.00,1.7,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,03:28,3.1,90,1.6,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1028.0,81.9,16.9,46,0.0,3.1,3.1,0,0,0.00,0.00,1.4,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,03:58,3.4,89,1.8,0.7,0.7,270,0.0,0.0,1027.8,81.9,16.9,46,0.7,3.4,3.4,0,0,0.00,0.00,1.2,0,0.0,270,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,04:28,4.0,87,2.0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1027.8,81.9,16.9,46,0.0,4.0,4.0,0,0,0.00,0.00,2.3,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,04:58,3.1,89,1.5,0.7,0.7,270,0.0,0.0,1027.9,81.9,16.8,45,0.7,3.1,3.1,0,0,0.00,0.00,0.9,0,0.0,270,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,05:28,3.3,89,1.7,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1028.0,81.9,16.8,45,0.0,3.3,3.3,0,0,0.00,0.00,1.6,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,05:58,3.3,90,1.8,0.7,0.7,270,0.0,0.0,1028.1,81.9,16.7,45,0.7,3.3,3.3,0,0,0.00,0.00,1.1,0,0.0,270,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,06:28,3.4,90,1.9,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1028.4,81.9,16.7,45,0.0,3.4,3.4,0,0,0.00,0.00,1.7,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,06:58,3.3,90,1.8,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1028.7,81.9,16.7,45,0.0,3.3,3.3,0,7,0.00,0.00,1.6,2,0.5,0,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,07:28,3.6,90,2.1,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1028.7,81.9,16.8,45,0.0,3.6,3.6,0,19,0.00,0.00,1.9,44,0.5,0,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,07:58,5.0,87,3.0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1029.0,81.9,16.9,44,0.0,5.0,5.0,0,29,0.00,0.00,3.5,125,0.5,0,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,08:28,6.6,83,3.9,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1029.4,81.9,17.2,43,0.0,6.6,6.6,0,38,0.00,0.00,5.3,218,0.5,0,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,08:58,8.4,76,4.4,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1029.7,81.9,17.7,43,0.0,8.4,8.4,0,43,0.00,0.00,7.2,311,0.5,0,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,09:28,9.6,70,4.4,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1029.8,81.9,18.1,43,0.0,9.6,9.6,0,48,0.00,0.00,8.4,397,0.5,0,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,09:58,12.3,65,5.9,0.7,0.7,270,0.0,0.0,1029.5,81.9,18.7,43,0.7,12.3,12.3,3,359,0.00,0.00,10.9,474,1.0,270,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,10:28,13.0,65,6.6,1.0,1.0,270,0.0,0.0,1029.9,81.9,19.0,42,1.0,13.0,13.0,4,411,0.00,0.00,11.5,538,1.5,270,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,10:58,14.6,63,7.6,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1029.7,81.9,19.3,42,0.0,14.6,14.6,4,425,0.00,0.00,14.0,588,1.5,0,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,11:28,14.3,62,7.1,2.0,2.0,314,0.0,0.0,1029.9,81.9,19.7,41,2.0,14.2,14.3,4,480,0.00,0.00,12.2,623,2.0,315,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,11:58,14.5,62,7.3,1.7,1.7,314,0.0,0.0,1029.7,81.9,20.1,40,1.7,14.5,14.5,3,322,0.00,0.00,12.7,641,2.0,315,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,12:28,14.1,64,7.4,1.0,1.0,337,0.0,0.0,1029.9,81.9,20.3,40,1.0,14.1,14.1,1,164,0.00,0.00,12.8,643,2.0,338,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,12:58,14.6,60,6.9,1.0,1.0,337,0.0,0.0,1029.5,81.9,20.3,40,1.0,14.6,14.6,0,78,0.00,0.00,13.2,629,2.0,338,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,13:28,14.6,58,6.4,0.7,0.7,337,0.0,0.0,1029.3,81.9,20.5,40,0.7,14.6,14.6,1,101,0.00,0.00,13.3,598,2.0,338,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,13:58,15.1,57,6.6,1.7,1.7,337,0.0,0.0,1029.0,81.9,20.8,40,1.7,15.1,15.1,2,247,0.00,0.00,13.1,551,2.0,338,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,14:28,14.9,55,5.9,1.0,1.0,337,0.0,0.0,1029.1,81.9,20.8,40,1.0,14.9,14.9,1,143,0.00,0.00,13.3,491,2.0,338,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,14:58,14.5,60,6.8,1.0,1.0,337,0.0,0.0,1028.9,81.9,20.8,40,1.0,14.5,14.5,1,111,0.00,0.00,13.1,417,2.0,338,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,15:28,14.7,58,6.5,0.7,0.7,337,0.0,0.0,1029.0,81.9,21.0,39,0.7,14.7,14.7,0,55,0.00,0.00,13.4,333,2.0,338,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,15:58,13.9,67,7.9,0.7,0.7,337,0.0,0.0,1028.9,81.9,20.9,40,0.7,13.9,13.9,0,41,0.00,0.00,12.9,241,2.0,338,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,16:28,13.6,67,7.6,0.7,0.7,337,0.0,0.0,1029.3,81.9,20.5,40,0.7,13.6,13.6,0,32,0.00,0.00,12.5,147,2.0,338,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,16:58,13.2,68,7.4,1.0,1.0,337,0.0,0.0,1029.3,81.9,21.4,38,1.0,13.2,13.2,0,25,0.00,0.00,11.9,61,2.0,338,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,17:28,12.3,74,7.8,0.7,0.7,337,0.0,0.0,1029.7,81.9,20.3,40,0.7,12.3,12.3,0,12,0.00,0.00,11.3,6,2.5,338,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,17:58,12.0,73,7.3,0.7,0.7,337,0.0,0.0,1029.9,81.9,19.6,43,0.7,12.0,12.0,0,0,0.00,0.00,10.9,0,2.5,338,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,18:28,11.6,66,5.5,2.7,2.7,337,0.0,0.0,1030.2,81.9,19.2,44,2.7,10.6,11.6,0,0,0.00,0.00,8.7,0,2.5,338,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,18:58,11.0,68,5.3,1.7,1.7,292,0.0,0.0,1030.4,81.9,18.9,45,1.7,10.6,11.0,0,0,0.00,0.00,8.8,0,2.5,292,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,19:28,10.3,70,5.1,0.7,0.7,270,0.0,0.0,1031.1,81.9,18.8,46,0.7,10.3,10.3,0,0,0.00,0.00,8.7,0,2.5,270,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,19:58,10.5,73,5.9,0.7,0.7,225,0.0,0.0,1030.4,81.9,18.7,46,0.7,10.5,10.5,0,0,0.00,0.00,9.1,0,2.5,225,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,20:28,10.1,74,5.7,2.0,2.0,248,0.0,0.0,1031.0,81.9,18.5,46,2.0,9.3,10.1,0,0,0.00,0.00,7.7,0,2.5,248,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,20:58,10.0,75,5.8,2.0,2.0,292,0.0,0.0,1031.4,81.9,18.5,46,2.0,9.2,10.0,0,0,0.00,0.00,7.6,0,2.5,292,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,21:28,9.7,77,5.9,1.7,1.7,292,0.0,0.0,1031.7,81.9,18.3,46,1.7,9.1,9.7,0,0,0.00,0.00,7.6,0,2.5,292,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,21:58,9.4,79,5.9,1.0,1.0,292,0.0,0.0,1031.9,81.9,18.1,47,1.0,9.4,9.4,0,0,0.00,0.00,7.8,0,2.5,292,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,22:28,9.5,80,6.2,1.0,1.0,292,0.0,0.0,1031.8,81.9,18.1,47,1.0,9.5,9.5,0,0,0.00,0.00,7.9,0,2.5,292,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,22:58,9.4,80,6.1,2.0,2.0,292,0.0,0.0,1032.2,81.9,18.0,47,2.0,8.5,9.4,0,0,0.00,0.00,7.1,0,2.5,292,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,23:28,9.3,79,5.8,1.7,1.7,292,0.0,0.0,1032.2,81.9,18.0,47,1.7,8.6,9.3,0,0,0.00,0.00,7.2,0,2.5,292,0.0,0.0
02/09/21,23:58,8.9,80,5.6,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1032.2,81.9,18.0,48,0.0,8.9,8.9,0,0,0.00,0.00,7.9,0,2.5,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,00:28,8.5,81,5.4,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1032.5,81.9,17.9,48,0.0,8.5,8.5,0,0,0.00,0.00,7.5,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,00:58,7.6,85,5.2,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1032.6,81.9,17.8,48,0.0,7.6,7.6,0,0,0.00,0.00,6.5,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,01:28,7.6,85,5.2,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1032.6,81.9,17.7,48,0.0,7.6,7.6,0,0,0.00,0.00,6.5,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,01:58,7.6,85,5.2,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1032.5,81.9,17.7,48,0.0,7.6,7.6,0,0,0.00,0.00,6.5,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,02:28,6.4,88,4.6,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1032.4,81.9,17.6,48,0.0,6.4,6.4,0,0,0.00,0.00,5.2,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,02:58,5.8,89,4.1,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1032.2,81.9,17.6,48,0.0,5.8,5.8,0,0,0.00,0.00,4.5,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,03:28,5.5,91,4.1,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1032.4,81.9,17.4,48,0.0,5.5,5.5,0,0,0.00,0.00,4.2,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,03:58,5.4,90,3.9,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1032.3,81.9,17.3,48,0.0,5.4,5.4,0,0,0.00,0.00,4.1,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,04:28,5.5,90,4.0,0.7,0.7,292,0.0,0.0,1032.5,81.9,17.3,48,0.7,5.5,5.5,0,0,0.00,0.00,3.7,0,0.0,292,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,04:58,5.1,90,3.6,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1032.7,81.9,17.2,48,0.0,5.1,5.1,0,0,0.00,0.00,3.7,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,05:28,4.1,92,2.9,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1032.9,81.9,17.2,48,0.0,4.1,4.1,0,0,0.00,0.00,2.6,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,05:58,4.0,93,3.0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1033.2,81.9,17.1,48,0.0,4.0,4.0,0,0,0.00,0.00,2.5,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,06:28,3.8,92,2.6,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1033.1,81.9,16.9,49,0.0,3.8,3.8,0,0,0.00,0.00,2.2,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,06:58,4.3,91,3.0,1.0,1.0,292,0.0,0.0,1033.7,81.9,16.9,49,1.0,4.3,4.3,0,6,0.00,0.00,2.1,2,0.5,292,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,07:28,4.5,91,3.2,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1033.5,81.9,17.0,48,0.0,4.5,4.5,0,17,0.00,0.00,3.0,47,0.5,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,07:58,5.6,87,3.6,1.0,1.0,292,0.0,0.0,1034.1,81.9,17.2,47,1.0,5.6,5.6,0,25,0.00,0.00,3.5,130,0.5,292,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,08:28,6.7,83,4.0,1.7,1.7,270,0.0,0.0,1034.2,81.9,17.6,46,1.7,5.6,6.7,0,31,0.00,0.00,4.2,224,0.5,270,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,08:58,7.9,80,4.7,0.7,0.7,225,0.0,0.0,1034.4,81.9,17.9,45,0.7,7.9,7.9,0,36,0.00,0.00,6.2,317,0.5,225,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,09:28,9.4,77,5.6,1.0,1.0,225,0.0,0.0,1034.2,81.9,18.5,45,1.0,9.4,9.4,0,45,0.00,0.00,7.7,404,0.5,225,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,09:58,12.5,72,7.6,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1034.3,81.9,18.9,44,0.0,12.5,12.5,3,368,0.00,0.00,11.9,481,1.0,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,10:28,14.7,63,7.7,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1034.2,81.9,19.3,43,0.0,14.7,14.7,4,432,0.00,0.00,14.2,545,1.5,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,10:58,15.2,53,5.7,3.1,3.1,248,0.0,0.0,1033.9,81.9,19.6,43,3.1,14.7,15.2,4,432,0.00,0.00,12.0,595,1.5,248,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,11:28,15.7,46,4.1,2.7,2.7,203,0.0,0.0,1033.8,81.9,20.0,41,2.7,15.5,15.7,5,515,0.00,0.00,12.5,629,2.0,202,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,11:58,15.9,45,4.0,3.7,3.7,203,0.0,0.0,1033.4,81.9,20.3,41,3.7,15.3,15.9,3,391,0.00,0.00,12.0,648,2.0,202,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,12:28,15.9,44,3.7,0.7,0.7,203,0.0,0.0,1032.8,81.9,20.7,40,0.7,15.9,15.9,1,114,0.00,0.00,14.0,650,2.0,202,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,12:58,16.1,47,4.8,1.0,1.0,270,0.0,0.0,1032.6,81.9,20.9,40,1.0,16.1,16.1,2,227,0.00,0.00,14.2,635,2.0,270,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,13:28,16.7,49,5.9,1.0,1.0,292,0.0,0.0,1032.4,81.9,21.0,39,1.0,16.7,16.7,1,159,0.00,0.00,15.1,604,2.0,292,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,13:58,15.9,48,4.9,2.0,2.0,292,0.0,0.0,1032.3,81.9,21.1,38,2.0,15.9,15.9,0,77,0.00,0.00,13.4,557,2.0,292,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,14:29,15.8,48,4.8,0.7,0.7,314,0.0,0.0,1032.0,81.9,21.1,38,0.7,15.8,15.8,0,55,0.00,0.00,14.1,494,2.0,315,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,14:59,15.9,49,5.2,1.7,1.7,314,0.0,0.0,1031.8,81.9,21.1,37,1.7,15.9,15.9,0,47,0.00,0.00,13.6,419,2.0,315,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,15:29,16.1,48,5.1,3.1,3.1,314,0.0,0.0,1031.8,81.9,21.4,37,3.1,15.8,16.1,1,143,0.00,0.00,12.8,334,2.0,315,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,15:59,15.4,52,5.6,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1031.6,81.9,21.2,37,0.0,15.4,15.4,0,38,0.00,0.00,14.4,242,2.0,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,16:29,15.1,52,5.3,4.8,4.8,292,0.0,0.0,1031.9,81.9,20.9,39,4.8,14.0,15.1,0,31,0.00,0.00,10.7,148,2.0,292,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,16:59,14.2,57,5.8,3.7,3.7,314,0.0,0.0,1031.5,81.9,20.8,39,3.7,13.3,14.2,0,24,0.00,0.00,10.6,61,2.0,315,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,17:29,13.2,61,5.8,2.7,2.7,314,0.0,0.0,1032.0,81.9,20.3,40,2.7,12.5,13.2,0,11,0.00,0.00,10.4,6,2.5,315,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,17:59,12.0,66,5.8,2.7,2.7,314,0.0,0.0,1032.2,81.9,19.9,41,2.7,11.1,12.0,0,0,0.00,0.00,9.2,0,2.5,315,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,18:29,10.8,71,5.7,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1032.4,81.9,19.4,42,0.0,10.8,10.8,0,0,0.00,0.00,9.8,0,2.5,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,18:59,9.4,76,5.4,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1032.5,81.9,19.2,42,0.0,9.4,9.4,0,0,0.00,0.00,8.4,0,2.5,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,19:29,8.1,81,5.0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1032.8,81.9,18.9,44,0.0,8.1,8.1,0,0,0.00,0.00,7.0,0,2.5,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,19:59,7.5,83,4.8,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1033.0,81.9,18.8,44,0.0,7.5,7.5,0,0,0.00,0.00,6.3,0,2.5,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,20:29,6.6,85,4.3,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1033.0,81.9,18.6,45,0.0,6.6,6.6,0,0,0.00,0.00,5.3,0,2.5,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,20:59,6.0,86,3.8,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1033.1,81.9,18.5,45,0.0,6.0,6.0,0,0,0.00,0.00,4.7,0,2.5,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,21:29,5.5,87,3.5,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1033.2,81.9,18.3,45,0.0,5.5,5.5,0,0,0.00,0.00,4.1,0,2.5,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,21:59,5.4,87,3.4,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1033.6,81.9,18.1,45,0.0,5.4,5.4,0,0,0.00,0.00,4.0,0,2.5,0,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,22:29,5.2,87,3.2,1.0,1.0,314,0.0,0.0,1033.4,81.9,18.0,45,1.0,5.2,5.2,0,0,0.00,0.00,3.0,0,2.5,315,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,22:59,5.9,86,3.7,0.7,0.7,314,0.0,0.0,1033.7,81.9,18.0,45,0.7,5.9,5.9,0,0,0.00,0.00,4.0,0,2.5,315,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,23:29,6.6,85,4.3,0.7,0.7,314,0.0,0.0,1033.6,81.9,18.0,45,0.7,6.6,6.6,0,0,0.00,0.00,4.8,0,2.5,315,0.0,0.0
03/09/21,23:59,6.8,85,4.5,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1033.4,81.9,18.0,45,0.0,6.8,6.8,0,0,0.00,0.00,5.6,0,2.5,0,0.0,0.0
04/09/21,00:29,6.5,87,4.5,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1033.6,81.9,18.0,45,0.0,6.5,6.5,0,0,0.00,0.00,5.3,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
04/09/21,00:59,6.6,87,4.6,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1033.7,81.9,18.0,45,0.0,6.6,6.6,0,0,0.00,0.00,5.4,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
04/09/21,01:29,7.0,86,4.8,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1033.6,81.9,18.0,45,0.0,7.0,7.0,0,0,0.00,0.00,5.8,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
04/09/21,01:59,7.6,84,5.1,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,1033.4,81.9,17.9,45,0.0,7.6,7.6,0,0,0.00,0.00,6.5,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0
```

Comment: You stated multiple questions at once and didn't showed what you tried so far. The first question could be answered by a Stackoverflow (SO) or google search. Since this seems to be you first question on SO, I tried to show you one approach in the answer. Please try to split all your questions, research them and only ask questions for single, specific problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library called pandas for this:

```
import pandas as pd # library you need to download and install, e.g. anaconda or pip

df = pd.read_csv('path\to\your\file.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

info = [
["01/09/21","00:28",7.1,75,3.0,3.7,3.7,292,0.0,0.0,1025.8,81.9,17.1,44,3.7,4.6,7.1,0,0,0.00,0.00,3.0,0,0.0,292,0.0,0.0],
["01/09/21","00:58",7.0,75,2.9,5.1,5.1,248,0.0,0.0,1025.9,81.9,17.0,44,5.1,3.8,7.0,0,0,0.00,0.00,1.9,0,0.0,248,0.0,0.0],
["01/09/21","01:28",6.9,74,2.6,4.1,4.1,248,0.0,0.0,1025.8,81.9,17.0,44,4.1,4.1,6.9,0,0,0.00,0.00,2.5,0,0.0,248,0.0,0.0],
["01/09/21","01:58",6.9,74,2.6,4.8,4.8,292,0.0,0.0,1025.7,81.9,16.9,45,4.8,3.8,6.9,0,0,0.00,0.00,2.0,0,0.0,292,0.0,0.0],
["01/09/21","02:28",6.8,76,2.9,3.7,3.7,270,0.0,0.0,1025.5,81.9,16.9,45,3.7,4.2,6.8,0,0,0.00,0.00,2.7,0,0.0,270,0.0,0.0],
["01/09/21","02:58",6.7,76,2.8,3.1,3.1,270,0.0,0.0,1025.4,81.9,16.8,45,3.1,4.5,6.7,0,0,0.00,0.00,3.0,0,0.0,270,0.0,0.0],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(info)

print(df.head())

df.to_csv("example.csv")
```

This should give you the results you are looking for.